# (Rocketchip + Sifive-blocks UART) Unable to make use of system printf() function

Tags: c++, c, uart, riscv, rocket-chip

I am currently working with the [Rocket Chip repo](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip) to generate a 32-bit width microcontroller. I removed the debug module (The SimDTM or SimJTAG) for compiling on VCS 2014, so for debugging purpose I need to add GPIO and UART. I added the GPIO and UART modules from the [Sifive-Blocks repo](https://github.com/sifive/sifive-blocks), and then modified the configuration of the Rocketchip accordingly (Add `WithUART` and `WithGPIO` into Configs, add `HasPeripheryUART` and `HasPeripheryUARTModuleImp` into ExampleRocketSubsystem etc.).

Then, in order to write to the UART, I wrote a `UartStdOutInit()` function as below:

```
void UartStdOutInit(void)
{
  *uartaddr32(UART_DIV) = DIVISOR;
  *uartaddr32(UART_TXEN) = TRUE; // tx enabled, stop bit 1 bit
  *uartaddr32(UART_RXEN) = TRUE; //rx enabled
  return;
}
```

With the header file like this:

```
#ifndef _UART_CONF_H
#define _UART_CONF_H

#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0
#define ERROR -1

typedef unsigned int U32;        //U32 is 32-bit length
#define UART_ADDR               0x54000000

#define UART_TXFIFO             0x00
#define UART_RXFIFO             0x04
#define UART_TXEN               0x08
#define UART_TXMARK             0x0a
#define UART_RXEN               0x0c
#define UART_RXMARK             0x0e

#define UART_IE                 0x10
#define UART_IP                 0x14
#define UART_DIV                0x18
#define UART_PARITY             0x1c
#define UART_WIRE4              0x20
#define UART_EITHER8OR9         0x24 \

#define uartaddr32(offset)  ((volatile U32 *)(UART_ADDR + offset))

#define DIVISOR 868 //10000000/115200 -1

/*Function declaration*/
void UartStdOutInit(void);
#endif
```

But after calling the Init function, I wasn't able to use either `printf()` or `putchar()` to write to my UART. If I used them, nothing will appear at the Txd line. The only way I can write to my UART is to create a new function like this:

```
void uartputchar(unsigned char c)
{
    *uartaddr32(UART_TXFIFO) = c;
}
```

And call it from a new `print()` function. Then my Txd line will toggle, and the data can be captured by a UART_capture module. But in this way I cannot use format strings, and it has been a big obstacle for my debugging process (still possible to hardcode through, but will be very messy and tedious). I have tried to find other resources but cannot, as most of them are doing FPGA projects or working from a IDE. Can anyone tell me what is missing or what is wrong with my UART implementation? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `print` related functions are not the ones defined in `stdio.h`, but rather the ones defined in `syscalls.c` -- actually in `syscalls.c` there are `#undef` to overwrite system functions like `putchar()`. So if I replace the function content of `putchar()` in `syscalls.c` with my own `uartputchar()`, the `printf()` will work with all the formatting etc. that have already been defined in `syscalls.c`.